# C - Wrong fibonacci numbers

Tags: c, math, fibonacci

I have written this C code to output Fibonacci numbers but I'm lost as to why it gives the wrong value, and also why the numbers occasionally go *down*. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

It gives me this sequence: 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 7, 13, 8, 21, 9, 34.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int MyFibonacciFunction(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (MyFibonacciFunction((n - 1)) + MyFibonacciFunction((n - 2)));
        }
    }
}

void main()
{

        int a = 0;
        while (a < 10) {
            {
                printf("%d\n", a);
                printf("%d\n", MyFibonacciFunction(a));
                a = (a + 1);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sequence looks nearly right, you would expect 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 7, 13, 8, 21, 9, 34 because you print both a and fibo(a)...

Comment: Many superfluous prentheses... and curly braces

Comment: remove `printf("%d\n", a);`.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code as follows,try this it solves your problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int MyFibonacciFunction(int n) {

      if(n == 0)
        return 0;
      else if(n == 1)
        return 1;
      else
        return (MyFibonacciFunction((n - 1)) + MyFibonacciFunction((n - 2)));

}

int main(void)
{

    int a = 0;
    while (a < 10)
        printf("%d\n", MyFibonacciFunction(a++));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please change to `while (a < 10) printf("%d\n", MyFibonacciFunction(a++));` to appease my ocd

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use recursion, then don't use it. If this is some recursion excercise, then it's ok. Iterative programming is faster and saves memory(a lot).